# How to use conditional-stataments as an input in a R function

Tags: r, function, conditional-statements

I am writing a function where one of the input is a condition. See the following example

sample data set

```
ab <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 5)
```

Function

`dat` is a matrix/data frame (e.g. `ab`)

`con` is the condition I want to use inside the function (e.g. `> 50`, `=< 80`, etc)

```
fil_dat <- function (dat, con ) {
  fildat <- data[which(rowMeans(dat)"the condition *con* should go here"),]
  return(fildat)
}
```

How do I insert the condition here? Also, there must be other ways to subset and derive `fildat`.I was thinking it would be easier with  `dplyr::filter`. But I can't figure out the right way to do it. Can anybody help, please? And, going one step further, can I use multiple conditions at once, something like `> 50 & <= 80`?

**Edit:** Sorry, I forgot to mention this before. It would be great if the function can also handle NULL conditional-statement (i.e. no condition). I know it won't make sense for this toy example, but for my actual function, it does. I also know I can write an `if-loop` inside a function to overcome this. But it would be great the sub-set function itself can handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can try `eval`

```
fil_dat <- function (dat, con = NULL ) {
  if (is.null(con)) return(dat)
  return(eval(str2expression(sprintf("dat[which(rowMeans(dat)%s),]",con))))    
}
```

which gives

```
> fil_dat(ab,"<=50")
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1   21   41   61   81
 [2,]    2   22   42   62   82
 [3,]    3   23   43   63   83
 [4,]    4   24   44   64   84
 [5,]    5   25   45   65   85
 [6,]    6   26   46   66   86
 [7,]    7   27   47   67   87
 [8,]    8   28   48   68   88
 [9,]    9   29   49   69   89
[10,]   10   30   50   70   90

> fil_dat(ab)
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1   21   41   61   81
 [2,]    2   22   42   62   82
 [3,]    3   23   43   63   83
 [4,]    4   24   44   64   84
 [5,]    5   25   45   65   85
 [6,]    6   26   46   66   86
 [7,]    7   27   47   67   87
 [8,]    8   28   48   68   88
 [9,]    9   29   49   69   89
[10,]   10   30   50   70   90
[11,]   11   31   51   71   91
[12,]   12   32   52   72   92
[13,]   13   33   53   73   93
[14,]   14   34   54   74   94
[15,]   15   35   55   75   95
[16,]   16   36   56   76   96
[17,]   17   37   57   77   97
[18,]   18   38   58   78   98
[19,]   19   39   59   79   99
[20,]   20   40   60   80  100
```

Comment: Thank you. It perfectly handles one condition at a time. I can do this again for the second condition if needed. I am still wondering if there is a better alternative to handle multiple conditions at once.

Comment: @MaMu Could you show some examples of multiple conditions you want to use?

Comment: It's already there in my original question.

Comment: @MaMu This is the simplest one that I can do so far. Perhaps we can wait for other more brilliant solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, also with `eval` but after `parse`.

```
fil_dat <- function (data, con, drop = FALSE) {
  con <- paste("rowMeans(data)", con)
  i <- eval(parse(text = con))
  data[which(i), , drop = drop]
}

ab <- matrix(1:100, ncol = 5)

fil_dat(ab, ">= 50")
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   10   30   50   70   90
# [2,]   11   31   51   71   91
# [3,]   12   32   52   72   92
# [4,]   13   33   53   73   93
# [5,]   14   34   54   74   94
# [6,]   15   35   55   75   95
# [7,]   16   36   56   76   96
# [8,]   17   37   57   77   97
# [9,]   18   38   58   78   98
#[10,]   19   39   59   79   99
#[11,]   20   40   60   80  100

fil_dat(ab, "== 50")
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]   10   30   50   70   90

fil_dat(ab, "== 50", TRUE)
#[1] 10 30 50 70 90
```